# Can you show me an example of Mixins with class-based views in Django? What is the usage?

Tags: python, django, mixins

I am new to Django, and I usually used function-based views. But I see that using mixins with class-based views way more powerful. I did a lot of research but I am still confused about how to use Mixins. How come Mixins are an excellent way of reusing code across multiple classes?

**When or Why I should use class-based views?**

If you show me an example or better way of explanation than it does in docs, I would be appreciated.

Comment: *But I see that using mixins with class-based views way more powerful* - class based views aren't necessarily better. [Django Views - the right way](https://spookylukey.github.io/django-views-the-right-way/index.html) is a recent guide that might persuade you to stick with function based views.

Comment: thank you, I write it because I see in the docs: "through the use of mixins, provides a toolkit that results in class-based generic views being more extensible and flexible than their function-based counterparts."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the documentation for that is perfect: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/

That's how I used mixins so far.

### Models

For models: Lets say that you want to have `created_at, updated_at` fields in every model that you have. I would create a TimestampableMixin where it could look like this.

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) (why `abstract`?)

```py
class TimestampableMixin(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And then I would just extend my other models with the mixin. All of the models which are inheriting the `TimestampableMixin` will have those fields included in them. Keep in mind that you can add more mixins into that `Post` Model, like `TaggingMixin` etc.

```py
class Post(TimestampableMixin, TaggingMixin):
    ...
```

### Views

I don't find myself using them in my views often but one time I've used them for repeatedly getting the same `context_data` and some `kwargs` from the url.

So I created a `DashboardMixin` with the following implemented methods.

```
class DashboardMixin:

    def get_context_data(self):
        ...

# and then in the Views
class IndexView(DashboardMixin, View):
    ...
```

**Keep in mind the [MRO(Method Resolution Order)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)!** - That's how python handles multiple inheritance.

That's how I used mixins within Django. You can apply that in almost every aspect of the framework. Eg. in the django's admin site, extending and adding more functionality to the `ModelAdmin`, in **Forms** and so on. The documentation that I linked is explaining all of that you will get a better idea when you read it.